Next.js 15 Client and Server Side Validation With Mantine Form and Server Actions
I am using Mantine form for my UI and client side validation: https://mantine.dev/form/validation/
Here is an example of using it:
import { useForm } from '@mantine/form';
import { NumberInput, TextInput, Button } from '@mantine/core';

function Demo() {
  const form = useForm({
    mode: 'uncontrolled',
    initialValues: { name: '', email: '', age: 0 },

    // functions will be used to validate values at corresponding key
    validate: {
      name: (value) => (value.length < 2 ? 'Name must have at least 2 letters' : null),
      email: (value) => (/^\S+@\S+$/.test(value) ? null : 'Invalid email'),
      age: (value) => (value < 18 ? 'You must be at least 18 to register' : null),
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.onSubmit(console.log)}>
      <TextInput
        label="Name"
        placeholder="Name"
        key={form.key('name')}
        {...form.getInputProps('name')}
      />
      <TextInput
        mt="sm"
        label="Email"
        placeholder="Email"
        key={form.key('email')}
        {...form.getInputProps('email')}
      />
      <NumberInput
        mt="sm"
        label="Age"
        placeholder="Age"
        min={0}
        max={99}
        key={form.key('age')}
        {...form.getInputProps('age')}
      />
      <Button type="submit" mt="sm">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}

I am trying to have both client and server side validation with server actions. A different library that is not UI based, conform, has an example of this:
https://conform.guide/integration/nextjs
Here is a snippet:
export function LoginForm() {
  const [lastResult, action] = useFormState(login, undefined);
  const [form, fields] = useForm({
    // Sync the result of last submission
    lastResult,

    // Reuse the validation logic on the client
    onValidate({ formData }) {
      return parseWithZod(formData, { schema: loginSchema });
    },

    // Validate the form on blur event triggered
    shouldValidate: 'onBlur',
    shouldRevalidate: 'onInput',
  });

  return (
    <form id={form.id} onSubmit={form.onSubmit} action={action} noValidate>
      

I have been attempting to have the same resulting code of onSubmit and action with Mantine form, but all attempts fail me. I have attempted the following as an example:
<form
  ref={formRef}
  onSubmit={form.onSubmit((values, event) => {
    event?.stopPropagation();
    formRef.current?.submit();
  })}
  action={formAction}
>

For some reason, the server action never gets triggered. I have a feeling that the conform library has some magic involved that allows this to work. I would just like to get the same working setup with Mantine form. Any help is appreciated.
